# Evaluation edition expired

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, license

I have a client that has a recently expired SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise Evaluation Edition.  I've been tasked to get it licensed and running SQL Server 2008 R2 Standard.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You have to install SQL Server 2008 r2 Standard edition side by side (if you want to do it on the same server) and then move the database using backup/restore method.

Below is an outline of what needs to be done (if you want to do it on the same server without installing a side by side SQL 2008R2 instance).

- backup all database on Enterprise Edition & script out the logins as well.
- uninstall Enterprise Edition
- install Standard Edition
- Patch it to latest SP
- restore databases
- Create logins and map orphan users (if any).

Also, Unless you're using Enterprise-only features, you should be able to use detach and attach method from Enterprise to Standard.

Refer to answer by Jonathan [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/113f62cb-f1ef-4e0a-9bf3-b97dccf1a87e/).

Also, refer to [this](http://skreebydba.com/2012/11/16/downgrading-sql-server-enterprise-to-standard-with-scripts/) approach with scripts... BUT WITH EXTREME CAUTION !! ... it uses detach/attach method and if you are using any enterprise features (which wont work in Standard edition) then the attach wont work.

Also, refer to [Version and Edition Upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) Matrix.

Comment: Note that Enterprise-only features still come into play with a backup/restore migration. We recently dealt with this when upgrading from 2008 Ent to 2012 Std (and rolling our own implementations of the one or two Enterprise features we really needed).

Comment: @db2 Yes. You are correct. My point was to highlight safe route - backup/restore vs detach/attach as in the former atleast you have good backups. There is a dmv that can see what features are enabled -- SELECT * FROM sys.dm_db_persisted_sku_features;

Comment: I can confirm that the "this approach with scripts" method works well if you can take the outage.  I've used this method several times and as long as the instance name and paths are installed the same as before you should be good.